# How can I calculate the joint PDF given a marginal pdf and a uniform distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, marginal-distribution

The random vector $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on $[-1,3] \times[-2,5]$
$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases} x\over2 &, 0 \le x \le 2, \\ 0 &, \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
a) Determine the joint PDF of X and Y

b) Compute $P((X,Y) \in A$, where $A$ is the interior of the triangle $M(-1,2), N(3,-2), P(3,5)$

My attempt:
For point a) I've thought about using the formula $f_X(x) = $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty {f_{X,Y}(x,y)} \,dy$, since we know that this is $x\over2$, I just need to find the $y$ interval. Theoretically, one solution would be $f_X(x) = $$\int_{0}^x {1\over2} \,dy$ which gives us $x\over2$. I'm not sure if this is right I basically just derivated $x\over2$ and thought which interval would give us this result from the integral. As for point b) I've sketched a drawing and it seems that triangle has an angle of 90 degrees at the B point. However, I believe I need to solve a) in order to be able to solve b). Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really mean $(X, Y)$ is distributed _uniformly_? You might want to rethink what you’re asking.

Comment: @Aruralreader I think so, I wrote it as the problem is stated

Comment: If $(X,Y)$ is distributed uniformly, doesn't that mean the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$ is the PDF of the uniform distribution on that region, i.e. one over the area? But then, how is the support of the marginal for $X$ $[0,2]$?

Comment: @Joe Yes, this was also something I was confused about.

Comment: @Joe Could it be a mistake in the problem statement or something? If it is, how would you normally find the joint PDF?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience finding joint PDFs. I think often, when I have, it was either from the context of the problem (knowing a relationship between the random variables), or because the variables were independent and the joint was the product of the marginals. If the random vector is uniformly distributed in that rectangular region, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent. But yes, it does seem to me like there is a mistake in the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is straightforward to go from joint to marginal. If $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, then going from marginal to joint is not possible.

since, $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on $[-1,3] \times[-2,5]$, hence $ {f_{X,Y}(x,y)}=c$ over that rectangular region($c$ is an unknown constant).

also,
$\int_{-1}^3\int_{-2}^5 {f_{X,Y}(x,y)} \,dy \,dx=1$

This gives $c=\frac{1}{28}$

Now, to get the marginal density of $X$, integrate out $Y$ as follows

$$f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty {f_{X,Y}(x,y)} \,dy=\int_{-2}^5 c \,dy=\frac{1}{4},\forall x\in[-1,3]$$

I could go on, but i guess it is clear now, that the problem has its own problems...